# What proof uses both the Riemann Hypothesis and its negation?

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, logic

Some time ago I happened to see a proof that was remarkable in that it used both the Riemann Hypothesis and its negation. That is, it considered the two cases: RH is true, and RH is false, obtaining, after a non-trivial chain of reasoning in each case, the theorem in question. I failed to bookmark it well enough that I can readily retrieve it, so I’m asking the community’s help.

What reminded me of this result was [this question on MO about famous vacuously true statements](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/138348/famous-vacuously-true-statements). Obviously, one of the cases in the proof is vacuous and, since it involves the Riemann Hypothesis, conceivably qualifies as being famous.

Comment: It seems opposite to logic, then it would be a false proof. It would be extremely interesting if correct.

Comment: @Mathgemini: That's exactly the reference I was looking for. Silly me, not to see it right under my nose, so to speak, as much as I consult Wikipedia! If you will post your comment as an answer, I will be glad to accept it.

Comment: FWIW, there is another statement such that, as someone else, elsewhere, pointed out, both the statement and its negation lead to the same conclusion, namely, we (earthlings) are alone in the universe, or we are not. In either case, it's fantastic.

Comment: We are not is reality but it is fantastic also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small list on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis#Excluded_middle